How do I get a specific window to float over a full-screen running game?
I'm a user who plays Overwatch. My natural viewing angle is narrow, so when I focus on the am in the middle, I never see the fitness bar. So I created a program that makes the fitness bar in the lower left side of the center positioned on the left side of the ultimate mark so that I can see the fitness bar better than before. But this is only supported in window mode. How can I run it in full screen?
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#pragma comment (lib, "dwmapi.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "gdiplus.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void RealTimeDisplay(HWND hwnd);
void UpdateCaptureBox(RECT& box, int left, int top, int right, int bottom);

// Global variables
RECT captureBox = { 160, 875, 425, 969 };
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
HWND editBox;
POINT clickOffset;
bool running = true;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"SimpleDisplayClass";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        L"SimpleDisplayClass",
        L"Simple Display",
        WS_POPUP,
        captureBox.left, captureBox.top,
        captureBox.right - captureBox.left,
        captureBox.bottom - captureBox.top,
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr
    );

    if (!hwnd) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create window." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure the window is topmost and transparent
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 255, LWA_ALPHA);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    std::thread displayThread(RealTimeDisplay, hwnd);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    running = false;
    displayThread.join();

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static bool dragging = false;
    static POINT startPoint = {};

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        dragging = true;
        SetCapture(hwnd);
        GetCursorPos(&startPoint);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &startPoint);
        break;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (dragging) {
            POINT cursorPos;
            GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);

            RECT windowRect;
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, &windowRect);

            int dx = cursorPos.x - (windowRect.left + startPoint.x);
            int dy = cursorPos.y - (windowRect.top + startPoint.y);

            MoveWindow(hwnd, windowRect.left + dx, windowRect.top + dy,
                windowRect.right - windowRect.left,
                windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top, TRUE);
        }
        break;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        dragging = false;
        ReleaseCapture();
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        running = false;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void RealTimeDisplay(HWND hwnd) {
    while (running) {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        HDC screenDC = GetDC(nullptr);
        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);

        int width = captureBox.right - captureBox.left;
        int height = captureBox.bottom - captureBox.top;

        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, width, height);
        SelectObject(memDC, hBitmap);

        BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, width, height, screenDC, captureBox.left, captureBox.top, SRCCOPY);

        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(hBitmap, nullptr);
        graphics.DrawImage(&bitmap, 0, 0, width, height);

        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
        ReleaseDC(nullptr, screenDC);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        // Adjust sleep time for 500fps
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(2000)); // 500fps = 1 frame every 2ms
    }
}

void UpdateCaptureBox(RECT& box, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    box.left = left;
    box.top = top;
    box.right = right;
    box.bottom = bottom;
}

int main() {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    return WinMain(hInstance, nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOW);
}


This is a completely different thing in full screen and you can't use GDI anymore. Google for "DirectX overlay", and it usually depends precisely on what's hooked (ie: here Overwatch)

You probably even need to resort to dll injection.

Just look around on the internet a bit... this question has been asked and answered a lot of times.

When the application is running full-screen, there's no such thing as OS windows any more. If you want something on screen you have to somehow interact with the applications rendering.
